# php constant with gettext

Tags: php, gettext

I am using config file which contains:
config.php

```
define('SYS_TITLE','My Application Title');
```

I load language local for gettext based on SESSION variable in another file included after the config file is loaded.
how to make it something like:

```
echo _(SYS_TITLE);
```

What is the best way to translate the SYS_TITLE without changing much of the code.

Comment: I don't understand. If you define your texts in constants, why use gettext at all? Won't a `echo SYS_TITLE` do the job already?

Comment: actually I started using gettext after I finished coding, that's why I thought that might be there some way to translate the constants. Unfortunately, it seems impossible, gettext accepts strings, no variables nor constants. thank you Pekka.

Answer (score 0):

If I get you right you are looking for a way to import translated string into some php code.

How about loading all your strings in XL in the first column and generating the php code in the second column with a simple concatenate() call?

If you store "Something in English" in A1, you can setup B1 as follows:

```
=CONCATENATE("define('SYS_TITLE','",A1,"');")
```

You end up with

```
A1                      B1
Something in english    define('SYS_TITLE','Something in english');
```

Comment: sorry sir, but I am using gettext library to have separate files for translations.

Answer (score 0):

You could just use:

```
echo _("SYS_TITLE");
```

and then create a .po file for all your translations. It wouldn't use the *value* of your constant, of course, but it's up to you to decide if that's acceptable. After all, you don't *need* the msgid to contain the default language's text literally.

You could also create some wrapper function for your gettext call:

```
function gt(string){
    if(defined(string)){
        echo constant(string);
    } else {
        echo _(string);
    }
}
```

Of course, accepting all the problems that this will bring along (like additional plural handling).

Answer (score 0):

You should also be able to do this:

```
echo _(constant("SYS_TITLE"));
```

This should retrieve the value of your constant, which will then be passed into your function call. I haven't tested it though, so I may be wrong.